# How use removeEventListener where second parameter is closure

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have

```
getEventNameFromInput() {
    this.inputName.addEventListener('keyup', this.eventName())
}
eventName() {
    let eventName = [];
    return (e) => {
        eventName.push(e.target.value)
           
    }
};
```

I try to use in second object but doesnt' work.    :

```
interfaceUser.inputName.removeEventListener('keyup', interfaceUser.eventName())
```

This and interfaceuser are  references the same instance of object.  getEventNameFromInput and eventName are in object InterfaceUser

Answer (score 2):

When you call `removeEventListener` you have to pass **the same function**.

With your existing code, every time you call `eventName`, it generates a new arrow function and returns that. An identical function will not do the job. You need the same function.

This means that you need to store the function when you create it, and then retrieve the value from the store next time you need it.

For example:

```
eventName() {
    if (!this.eventHandler) {
        let eventName = []; 
        this.eventHandler = (e) => {
            eventName.push(e.target.value)
        }
    }
    return this.eventHandler;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to go with custom events as specified here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

form.addEventListener('awesome', e => console.log(e.detail.text()));

textarea.addEventListener('input', function() {
  // Create and dispatch/trigger an event on the fly
  // Note: Optionally, we've also leveraged the "function expression" (instead of the "arrow function expression") so "this" will represent the element
  this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('awesome', {
    bubbles: true,
    detail: {
      text: () => textarea.value
    }
  }))
});
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea></textarea>
</form>
```